# Python board game project - List index out of range

Tags: python

I have a board game program that uses coordinates so you can select units on the board.

To do this I've been using lists like Player1xcoords and Player2ycoords, where the x coordinates of a certain piece are stored in the x coord list and vice versa for y coordinates.

[Lists Before the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l29QP.png)

My problem comes up when I try to select something in the first turn. If the other player doesn't have any units, then I am given this error:

[Index out of range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IRQE.png)

This shouldn't be the case because I have added the number 77 to each one of the player 2 lists, so there should be something in the index.

The program works when I pick out an ore, so I'm pretty confused.

[77 Coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaZB1.png)

I am trying to get the program to go through each list and read through them with the i variable, essentially something like this -

> Is the inputted x coordinate in Player 2's x coordinates list?

- No

> Is it in player 1's list?

- No
  ....

> Not found in any list, retrying with i + 1

Tried looking over other Stackoverflow questions similar to mine, never figured out a way to fix it. Thanks if you do help.

Essentially, my current problem is that in ' turn 1 ' of the program, I cannot pick out units because it is going over Player 2's list and giving me an index error. I thought filling it out with a placeholder would fix this, but it didn't. I need help fixing this specific issue as of now.

Full unit choice script
[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLfTX.png)

```
elif choice == "3":
        if Turn == True:
          print(Player1ListNames)
          selected_unit = str(input(" What Unit are you going to use?"))
          loop = 1
          i = 0
          while loop == 1:
            if selected_unit == Player1ListNames[i]: 
              loop = 0
              selected_unit = Player1ListUnits[i]
              xcoord = int(input("X Coordinate"))
              ycoord = int(input("Y Coordinate"))
              range = selected_unit.range
              xcoordselection = selected_unit.locationx
              ycoordselection = selected_unit.locationy
              i = 0
              coordinateloop = 1
              while coordinateloop == 1:
                if xcoord <= (xcoordselection + range) and xcoord >= (xcoordselection - range) or xcoord == xcoordselection:               #WORK HERE
                  if ycoord <= (ycoordselection + range) and ycoord >= (ycoordselection - range) or ycoord == ycoordselection:
                    if xcoord == Player2xCoords[i] and ycoord == Player2yCoords[i]:
                      Target_Unit = Player2ListUnits[i]
                      print("You have selected the unit at", xcoord, ycoord, " It is a ", Target_Unit.symbol)
                      unitoption = input(" What would you like to do to this unit? \n - Attack \n - Back \n")
                      if unitoption == "attack":
                        print("Your unit attacks, dealing", str(selected_unit.damage), "Damage")
                        Target_Unit.health = Target_Unit.health - selected_unit.damage
                        print(" The enemy unit has " + str(Target_Unit.health))
                        if Target_Unit.health <= 0:
                          Target_Unit.Symbol = "  "
                          Player2ListUnits[i] = ""
                          Player2ListNames[i] = ""
                        coordinateloop = 0
                        Actions = Actions - 1
                    elif xcoord == Player1xCoords[i] and ycoord == Player1yCoords[i]:
                        Target_Unit = Player1ListUnits[i]
                        print("You have selected your own unit at", xcoord, ycoord)
                        unitoption = input(" What would you like to do to this unit? \n - Attack \n - Back \n")
                    elif xcoord == OrexCoords[i] and ycoord == OreyCoords[i]:
                        if OrexCoords[i] == LimitedOre1.locationx or OrexCoords[i] == LimitedOre2.locationx:
                          if selected_unit.symbol == "W ":
                            choice = input("You have selected a Limited Ore, would you like to \n - Mine \n - Back \n")
                            if choice == "mine":
                              if selected_unit.satchelsize <= 0:
                                print("Your miner's satchel is full")
                                coordinateloop = 0
                              else:
                                print("Your Worker mines and gains a piece of gold, deposit it at your HQ to get cash.")
                                selected_unit.satchelspace = selected_unit.satchelspace + 1
                                selected_unit.satchelsize = selected_unit.satchelsize - 1
                                coordinateloop = 0
                                Actions = Actions - 1
                            elif choice == "Back":
                              coordinateloop = 0
                            else:
                              print("You cannot mine with a unit that isn't a worker")
                              coordinateloop = 0
                    elif xcoord == HQ1Coordinates[i]:
                      if ycoord == HQ1Coordinates[i + 1]:
                        print("You have selected Player 1s HQ")
                    elif i > len(Player2xCoords):
                        if i > len(Player1xCoords):
                          print("The square you have selected is empty")
                    else:
                        i = i + 1
                  else: 
                    print("Your y range is above the range, try again")
                    ycoord = int(input())
                else:
                  print("Your x range is above the unit range, try again")
                  xcoord = int(input())
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not coming with a miracle solution but rather with a set of advices :

- You have multiple and multiple lists representing data that goes with each other, and that can not exist one without the other. Instant of doing this, you could use a list of `Piece` object, let's say, with Piece being a class regrouping all your data. You can learn about classes in Python [here](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/tutorial/classes.html). It could also be a good idea to make a `Player` class.
- For your code to appear cleaner and for it to be easily readable by other programmers, you should respect the given language standards. For python, the standard of variable naming, as an example, is snake_case. `Player1ListNames` would become `player_1_list_names` for example. You can learn a lot more about PEP8 standard, which is most of the time a really good line to follow [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)
- Your case has some things that are not so clear... For example you are trying to add 77 to `Player2[x/y]coords`, so I would assume you are trying to create a piece which as coordinates [77,77] on you board, but I also assume your board not have a size of 77 .... So the semantic of your code here may be wobbly.
- I can also see that your error points toward the line 481 of your code. Working with such big code files is very hard, and gessing the size of your project, it is too big. Try splitting your code in many functions, each doing precise job, and split those functions in groups that you can split in several files).

You only give very few code here to be able to point where the problem is so I'll just give a single assumption. You may be trying to index the game from index 1 when lists are starting at index 0, so you get out of bound not accessing lists properly.

Comment: Sorry for the initially undetailed question and the poor naming scheme, haven't used sites like these before and I've mostly just programmed for smaller college projects.

For the coordinates of 77, I was putting in as a placeholder so there would be something inside the list, that way the program could read over it, see that it's not any number inputted, then follow through to the rest of them.

I'll look over the sites you have linked, thank you for the help!